# Java SocketChannel equivalent in Erlang

Tags: java, erlang

Is there an Erlang equivalent of the Java SocketChannel class? Need to be able to handle multiple client socket connections using one Erlang process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gen_tcp interface allows you to interact quite easily with multiple sockets by a single Erlang process.  Use the {active, once} socket option or, if you're feeling lucky, {active, true} socket option.  For one/lots of very busy sockets, the latter can risk creating more messages to your Erlang process's mailbox than it can handle, hence {active, once} being the preferred option.

See:
  http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html
and
  http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html

The option is usually specified in the gen_tcp:listen() or gen_tcp:connect() calls, though you can also change the 'active' mode setting on a socket using inet:setopts().